# Get List of Records between two times C# Linq To Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my application, I am wanting to fill a list with records from the database that match specific conditions:

```
public ActionResult SelectYearGraph(int year)
{
    var lstAllSummaries = db.Summaries.ToList();

    var lstMonths =
       lstAllSummaries.Where(x => x.FlightDay.Year == year)
           .Select(x => x.TestDay.Month)
           .Distinct()
           .OrderBy(x => x)
           .ToList();

    List<string> lstMonthNames = new List<string>();
    List<int> lstCountSummaries = new List<int>();
    List<int> lstCountDailySummariesDifferentTime = new List<int>();

    var tsSix = new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0);
    var tsTen = new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0);

    foreach (var item in lstMonths)
    {
        var monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(item);
        lstMonthNames.Add(monthName);
        foreach (var item in lstMonths)
        {
            var monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(item);
            lstMonthNames.Add(monthName);
            lstCountDailySummaries.Add(lstAllSummaries.Count(x => x.FlightDay.Month == item && x.FlightDay.Year == year 
            && (x.FlightDay.TimeOfDay >= tsSix && x.FlightDay.TimeOfDay <= tsTen)
            && !x.deleted));
            lstCountDailySummariesDifferentTime.Add(lstAllSummaries.Count(x => x.FlightDay.Month == item && x.FlightDay.Year == year
            && (x.FlightDay.TimeOfDay > tsTen || x.FlightDay.TimeOfDay < tsSix)
            && !x.deleted));
        }
    }
    ... // more down here but not relevant to question
}
```

When I run this, I get a runtime error:

> The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I have tried [Date and Time Canonical Functions for LINQ-to-Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(VS.100).aspx), but I am receiving the same error.

How do I get all records between 6am and 10pm?

Comment: Remove all `.TimeOfDay` calls

Comment: BTW, your current design will query the database upwards of 25 times.  once for the list of months and then twice for each set of counts.

Comment: If you do that you are pulling your entire database into memory and then filtering.  You can do all of this work in the database query engine.  (see my answer below) ... worst case you should filter the year and deleted before your `.ToList()`

Comment: Better still write a view, user function or stored proc.

Comment: @MatthewWhited just edited.. called the database once to get the full list, then extract the wanted data from that list without having to call db multiple times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `TimeOfDay` just reading `Hour`, `Minute`, `Second` of your `DateTime` will give you the same result in your case.

> the TimeOfDay property returns a TimeSpan value that represents a DateTime value's time component.

So just change your code to:

```
...
&& (DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.TestDay.Hour, x.TestDay.Minute,x.TestDay.Second) > DbFunctions.CreateTime(6,0,0) 
&& (DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.TestDay.Hour, x.TestDay.Minute, x.TestDay.Second) < DbFunctions.CreateTime(22,0,0))
...
```

The problem with looking for times which cross midnight is that whereas a time can be both after 6am AND before 10pm the same is not true for after 10pm AND before 6am.

You'll need to change your AND to an OR

```
...
&& (
  (DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.TestDay.Hour, x.TestDay.Minute,x.TestDay.Second) > DbFunctions.CreateTime(22,0,0) 
  || (DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.TestDay.Hour, x.TestDay.Minute, x.TestDay.Second) < DbFunctions.CreateTime(6,0,0))
)
...
```

Comment: I've edited my question, because now I want to get the records between 10:01PM and 5:59AM and I am getting returned `0` records and I know there are records between those two times.. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: which month should the time after midnight be included with?

Comment: anyway, just change the bounds based on your requirements.

Comment: The following month

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from x in db.Summaries
            let time = DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.TestDay.Hour, x.TestDay.Minute, x.TestDay.Second)
            where x.FlightDay.Year == year
                && !x.deleted
                && (time < DbFunctions.CreateTime(6, 0, 0))
                && (time > DbFunctions.CreateTime(22, 0, 0))
            group x by x.FlightDay.Month into summaries
            let month = summaries.Key
            select new
            {
                Month = month,
                Count = summaries.Count(),
                DifferentCount = (from d in db.DailySummaries
                                  let timed = DbFunctions.CreateTime(d.TestDay.Hour, d.TestDay.Minute, d.TestDay.Second)
                                  where d.FlightDay.Year == year && d.FlightDay.Month == month                    
                                        && !d.deleted
                                        && (timed < DbFunctions.CreateTime(6, 0, 0))
                                        && (timed > DbFunctions.CreateTime(22, 0, 0))
                                  select d).Count(),
            };
```